# Examples of b-connected sets?

Tags: general-topology

> B is a b-open set if $B\subset Cl(IntB) \cup Int(ClB)$

> A topological space $X$ is b-disconnected if it can be expressed as a union of two disjoint non-empty b-open sets. Otherwise, $X$ is said to be b-connected.

Now I am only looking for some interesting examples of b- connected sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimal Example**

DanielWainfleet has shown  every nonempty open set is dense. We can use this to construct a minimal example using finite topological spaces.

Finite topological spaces are just directed graphs. The closure of $\{x\}$ is everything that can be reached from $x$ by following arrows starting at $x$. Writing $b \preceq a$ to mean there is an edge from $a$ to $b$ then closed sets means downwards-closed with respect to $\preceq$. Open sets means upwards-closed with respect to $\preceq$. Formally $B$ is closed and $U$ is open iff

$$B = \{x \in X: \exists b \in B \ : \ x \preceq  b \} \qquad \qquad U = \{x \in X: \exists u \in U \ : \ u \preceq  x \}$$

The interior of a set is the maximal upwards-closed subset. The closure of a set is the downwards closure:

$$Cl(A) = \{x \in X: \exists x_i \in X, a \in A \text{ with } x \prec x_1 \prec \ldots \prec x_n \prec a\}.$$

Using this we can construct a minimal example on the set $X = \{*\} \cup Y$ for any $Y$.  Add any choice of other edges such that:

(1) each point of $Y$ is accessible from $*$ by following arrows.

(2)  $*$ is not accessible from any point of $Y$ by following arrows.

For example the space might look like this:

[image]

Note that every point is accessible from $*$; and $*$ is not accessible from any other point. It follows that any set $A$ with $* \notin A$ has  $Cl(Int(A))=Int(Cl(A)) = \varnothing$.

It follows that every nonempty $b$-open set contains $*$ and so there is no $b$-disconnection.

Comment: I love this example and would like to use it in my research paper that I am writing. Can you allow me to?

Comment: The paper is titled "Brown-McCoy radical and its properties in B-topological rings"

Comment: Also by last line you mean "every non-empty b-open set A that contains $*$ is b-connected". The way you have written means every b-open set is b-connected, which clearly is false.

Comment: Feel free to use the example in your paper. Cite it by clicking the Cite button at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: In the last paragraph I mean every nonempty b-open set contains $\ast$.

Comment: Thanks Daron...

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

(1). Open sets are  b-open, because if $B$ is open then $B=Int(B),$ so $Cl(Int(B))\cup Int(Cl(B))\supseteq Cl(Int(B))=Cl(B)\supset B.$

So if $X$ is disconnected then $X$ is b-disconnected.

(2). A set $B$ is called regular-closed iff $B=Cl(Int(B)).$ A closed set $B$ is b-open iff $B$ is regular-closed. Proof: (i). If $B$ is regular-closed then $$Cl(Int(B))\cup Int(Cl(B))\supseteq Cl(Int(B))=B.$$ (ii). If $B$ is closed and b-open then $$B\subseteq Cl(Int(B))\cup Int(Cl(B))=$$ $$=Cl(Int(B))\cup Int(B)=$$ $$=Cl(Int(B)\subseteq $$ $$\subseteq Cl(B)=B.$$ So by (1), if $B$ is a regular-closed subset of $X$ with $\emptyset\ne B\ne X$ then $X$ is b-disconnected.

If $C$ is $any$ subset of $X$ then $Cl(Int (C))$ is regular-closed, i.e. $Cl(Int (C))=Cl(Int (Cl(Int (C)))).$ This well-known result has been proven by myself and others elsewhere on this site. (I gave a very simple proof). So by the previous paragraph and by (1), if $X$ is b-connected, then any non-empty open subset of $X$  must be dense in $X.$ Thus if $X$ is b-connected and $X$ has more than one point then $X$ cannot be Hausdorff.

(3). If the topology on $X$ is discrete then every subset of $X$ is its own interior and its own closure so every subset of $X$ is b-open, and if $\{x,y\}\subseteq B\subseteq X$ with $x\ne y$, then $B$ is b-disconnected because $\{x\}$  and $B\setminus \{x\}$ are both b-open, so the b-component of $x$ must be $\{x\}.$

Addendum: Discrete spaces are Hausdorff. If $X$ is Hausdorff then any $Y\subset X$ is Hausdorff, so by (2), if $Y$ has more than one point then $Y$ is b-disconnected. So every Hausdorff space $X$ is hereditarily b-disconnected.

(4). If $X=\emptyset$  or if $X$ has exactly one member then $X$ is b-connected. Perhaps someone can present a more interesting example.

Addendum regarding (2): If every non-empty open subset of $X$ is dense in $X,$ this is insufficient (by itself) to imply $X$ is b-connected. Two counter-examples are (i) the coarse topology on a set with more than one point; (ii) the co-finite topology on an infinite $X.$

Answer (score 0):

Every subset of the real line is $b$-disconnected. **Edit:** In fact every subset is totally $b$-disconnected.

The first step to prove this is to find some simple examples of $b$-open sets that are not open sets. What have you found so far?

And what does the $b$ stand for?

Comment: b comes from here- http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/mv/205/mv961209.pdf

Comment: I found R itself to be b-disconnected. I need to know something about total b disconnected examples.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is totally b-disconnected

Comment: Then what do b-connected sets look like?

Comment: What is your full name Daron?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth It's Daron Anderson.